# Is there a way to keep a Textbox triggered on Enter from accepting only spacebars

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program that selects random colors, and pretty much every aspect of it is working to this point.

How it works: You can use either the return key, or a button to add the text from the textbox to the listbox.

How I'd like it to act: Currently it doesn't accept no entry, so if textbox1.Text = "" it doesn't insert it to the listbox, but if the user just types "space""space""space" it will accept the blank text. I'd like to avoid that so there are no blank entries in the listbox.

Relevant Code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    Try
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If TextBox1.Text = "" Then

            Else
                lstColors.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
                TextBox1.Text = ""
            End If
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You could remove spaces before comparing with blank: `If TextBox1.Text.Trim() = "" Then`

Comment: If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.  It did exactly what I wanted.  Thank you very much. I'd never even heard of the Trim()

Comment: That's good! Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove spaces (using [`Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx)) before comparing with blank:

```
If TextBox1.Text.Trim() = "" Then
```